# Get the user sys_id using REST API in ServiceNow?

Tags: java, rest, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am trying to get the user `sys_id` by `username` using the `SNOW REST API`. But I couldn't find a way of doing it in the `SNOW API` doc.

Is it impossible to do so or any other alternative way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a simple GET call. sys_id isn't returned on the default fields but will be returned if you explicitly request it:

```
https://[your instance].service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user?sysparm_query=user_name%3D[your username]&sysparm_fields=sys_id&sysparm_limit=1
```

The REST api explorer is very handy for building and testing queries like this. You can find it by searching the navigator.