# How to get current user's sys id in ServiceNow when using REST APIs?

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I created an "Login with ServiceNow" OAuth flow via Authcode grant (I don't have username). As of now, I only am aware of the instance URL and access token - how do I use this to get the authenticating user's sys_id/other details?

I tried hitting `sys_user` endpoint - but it returns all users.

Also couldn't find any API from their [documentation](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/utah/rest).

P.S. Not similar to [Get the user sys_id using REST API in ServiceNow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56898872/get-the-user-sys-id-using-rest-api-in-servicenow) since the answer expects the developer to know the username

Answer (score 0):

If it is a scripted rest api, you can easily assign value to an attribute.
For example
`body.USER = gs.getUserID();`

Comment: Unfortunately, no, this is not a scripted API.